# Como importar dados (inserts) para um modelo (.MWB) no workbench?

Tags: mysql

No workbench eu posso inserir dados no modelo individualmente por tabela da forma abaixo, depois quando utilizar o forward engineer é só habilitar o Create Inserts no arquivo SQL que ele gera, segue:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém para fazer isso para centenas de tabelas é muito oneroso (exportar do servidor para CSV e depois importar, uma a uma), minha pergunta é, existe uma forma de importar dados de um servidor mysql para um modelo workbench?, no caso seria o mesmo modelo fisicamente que está no servidor.

Answer (score 1):

É possivel realizar um dump do seu banco de dados pelo workbench tem q clicar com o botao direito em cima da base e pedir pra exportar mas esse processo é demorado.

Eu recomendo usar linha de comando:
Você disse q a estrutura da tabela tá ok, então seria só os dados então no server no command do shell se for ubuntu vc coloca esse comando

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u user -ppassword --no-create-info banco > minhabase.sql
```

caso vc queira as query para criar as tabelas e etc seria:

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u user -ppassword banco > minhabase.sql
```

Para restaurar você faz assim

```
mysql -h localhost -u user -ppassword banco < minhabase.sql
```

Para fazer esses comandos no windows, deve-se entrar no MSDOS "Ctrl+R -> 'cmd' enter"
Navegar ate onde está seu mysql, entrar na pasta bin. Pronto agora pode fazer os comandos.